# ffmpeg: Preserve timecode when converting mov to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, transcoding, timecode

This seems simple enough.  I want to do a basic conversion of a .mov file to a .mp4 file using ffmpeg.  The hitch seems to be that I also need to preserve the timecode.

I've looked at many posts from around the web and specifically:

[ffmpeg Cut a media preserving all streams but also all metadata, timecodes and everything else](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16965/ffmpeg-cut-a-media-preserving-all-streams-but-also-all-metadata-timecodes-and-e?newreg=e35f1e9dd7fd4117b67f91693713ac51)

[ffmpeg: preserve timecode when converting mp4 to mov](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17948/ffmpeg-preserve-timecode-when-converting-mp4-to-mov?rq=1)

I started with a very simple command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mov output.mp4
```

Then I tried to preserve metadata:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mov -map_metadata 0 output.mp4
```

Then, maybe, preserve a header?

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mov -flags global_header output.mp4
```

When I open the output .mp4 file in Adobe Premiere, I see Timecode.  However, when I open it in Quicktime, I do not get timecode.  (Quicktime does show the timecode in the original .mov file).

If it helps, this is the ffmpeg I am using:

```
ffmpeg version N-95032-g3104100a12 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20190918
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 58.101 / 58. 58.101
  libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.102 /  7. 58.102
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Adding Debug Output from FFMPEG:

```
C:\ffmpeg -y -loglevel 48 -i "inputVideo.mov" "outputVideo.mp4"

ffmpeg version N-95032-g3104100a12 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20190918
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 58.101 / 58. 58.101
  libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.102 /  7. 58.102
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument '48'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'inputVideo.mov'.
Reading option 'outputVideo.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument 48.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url inputVideo.mov.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: inputVideo.mov.
[NULL @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Opening 'inputVideo.mov' for reading
[file @ 0000023f4e5ebdc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] ISO: File Type Major Brand: qt
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Processing st: 0, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 108909
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Processing st: 1, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 108909
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Processing st: 2, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 68068
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 18549647 bytes read:196608 seeks:5 nb_streams:4
[prores @ 0000023f4e5efe00] Auto bitdepth precision. Use 10b decoding based on codec tag.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] Probe buffer size limit of 5000000 bytes reached
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023f4e5ead80] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 23634243 bytes read:5248982 seeks:5 frames:10
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'inputVideo.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2019-05-21T11:17:22.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:02.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 203170 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng), 0, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T11:17:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : AJA Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng), 0, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T11:17:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : AJA Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng), 9, 1/30000: Video: prores (Standard), 1 reference frame (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(tv, unknown/reserved/reserved, progressive), 1920x1080, 0/1, 135462 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T11:17:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : AJA Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
      timecode        : 12:48:34:12
    Stream #0:3(eng), 1, 1/30000: Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0/1, 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 0
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T11:17:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : AJA Time Code Handler
      reel_name       : 001
      timecode        : 12:48:34:12
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url outputVideo.mp4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: outputVideo.mp4.
[file @ 0000023f4f76ed00] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 12 logical cores
[prores @ 0000023f4e68d880] Auto bitdepth precision. Use 10b decoding based on codec tag.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 13 times
[graph 0 input from stream 0:2 @ 0000023f4f41bac0] Setting 'video_size' to value '1920x1080'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:2 @ 0000023f4f41bac0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '66'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:2 @ 0000023f4f41bac0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/30000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:2 @ 0000023f4f41bac0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:2 @ 0000023f4f41bac0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:2 @ 0000023f4f41bac0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30000/1001'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:2 @ 0000023f4f41bac0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv422p10le tb:1/30000 fr:30000/1001 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
[format @ 0000023f52ab0500] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21|yuv420p10le|yuv422p10le|yuv444p10le|nv20le|gray|gray10le'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000023f4e602740] query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] using mv_range_thread = 24
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2, 10-bit
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] 264 - core 158 r2984 3759fcb - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=81 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0000023f4f2358c0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0000023f4f2358c0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0000023f4f2358c0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 's32'
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0000023f4f2358c0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x4'
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0000023f4f2358c0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:s32 samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x4
[format_out_0_1 @ 0000023f4f236fc0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'fltp'
[format_out_0_1 @ 0000023f4f236fc0] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '96000|88200|64000|48000|44100|32000|24000|22050|16000|12000|11025|8000|7350'
[format_out_0_1 @ 0000023f4f236fc0] auto-inserting filter 'auto_resampler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'format_out_0_1'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000023f4e602480] query_formats: 4 queried, 6 merged, 3 already done, 0 delayed
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0000023f4f236dc0] [SWR @ 0000023f4f23a480] Using fltp internally between filters
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0000023f4f236dc0] ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s32 r:48000Hz -> ch:1 chl:mono fmt:fltp r:48000Hz
Output #0, mp4, to 'outputVideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
    Stream #0:0(eng), 0, 1/30000: Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p10le(top coded first (swapped)), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, q=-1--1, 0.03 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T11:17:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : AJA Video Media Handler
      timecode        : 12:48:34:12
      encoder         : Lavc58.58.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(eng), 0, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (24 bit), delay 1024, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T11:17:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : AJA Sound Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.58.101 aac
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 76 times
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 69 times
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 19 times
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   0 QP=35.73 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:8160 P:0    SKIP:0    size=155655 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   1 QP=35.31 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:8   I:224  P:4523 SKIP:3413 size=36833 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   2 QP=37.99 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:4   I:3    P:2549 SKIP:5602 size=3687 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   3 QP=38.37 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:2   I:0    P:2182 SKIP:5970 size=2137 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   4 QP=38.56 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:6   I:2    P:1608 SKIP:6549 size=1637 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   5 QP=35.39 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:16  I:125  P:4484 SKIP:3551 size=30078 bytes
[out_0_0 @ 0000023f52ab0340] EOF on sink link out_0_0:default.
[out_0_1 @ 0000023f4f235ec0] EOF on sink link out_0_1:default.
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   6 QP=37.63 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:12  I:7    P:2561 SKIP:5582 size=3440 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   7 QP=38.90 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:10  I:0    P:2554 SKIP:5602 size=2205 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   8 QP=38.55 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:14  I:1    P:1824 SKIP:6334 size=1733 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=   9 QP=35.35 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:24  I:131  P:4353 SKIP:3676 size=27721 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  10 QP=37.66 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:20  I:2    P:2437 SKIP:5706 size=3120 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  11 QP=38.47 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:18  I:0    P:2291 SKIP:5867 size=2048 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  12 QP=39.01 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:22  I:0    P:1762 SKIP:6393 size=1558 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  13 QP=35.32 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:32  I:117  P:4134 SKIP:3909 size=23844 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  14 QP=38.39 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:28  I:3    P:2342 SKIP:5805 size=3295 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  15 QP=38.20 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:26  I:3    P:2171 SKIP:5984 size=2142 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  16 QP=38.92 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:30  I:0    P:1867 SKIP:6292 size=1695 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  17 QP=35.25 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:40  I:108  P:4151 SKIP:3901 size=23536 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  18 QP=37.68 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:36  I:2    P:2360 SKIP:5786 size=2840 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  19 QP=38.72 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:34  I:0    P:1924 SKIP:6230 size=1927 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  20 QP=39.59 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:38  I:1    P:1743 SKIP:6410 size=1597 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  21 QP=35.33 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:48  I:89   P:3900 SKIP:4171 size=20888 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  22 QP=37.94 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:44  I:2    P:2193 SKIP:5954 size=2763 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  23 QP=38.76 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:42  I:1    P:1882 SKIP:6272 size=1841 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  24 QP=38.76 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:46  I:0    P:1637 SKIP:6514 size=1477 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  25 QP=35.26 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:56  I:83   P:4037 SKIP:4040 size=21764 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  26 QP=37.71 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:52  I:2    P:2246 SKIP:5903 size=2798 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  27 QP=40.06 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:50  I:0    P:1864 SKIP:6292 size=1875 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  28 QP=39.06 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:54  I:0    P:1683 SKIP:6472 size=1548 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  29 QP=35.33 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:64  I:102  P:3945 SKIP:4113 size=20617 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  30 QP=37.61 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:60  I:0    P:2099 SKIP:6046 size=2867 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  31 QP=39.41 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:58  I:0    P:1696 SKIP:6457 size=1805 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  32 QP=38.90 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:62  I:2    P:1322 SKIP:6830 size=1546 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  33 QP=35.35 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:72  I:89   P:3725 SKIP:4346 size=18266 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  34 QP=38.31 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:68  I:1    P:2114 SKIP:6031 size=2637 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  35 QP=38.78 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:66  I:0    P:1736 SKIP:6417 size=1799 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  36 QP=39.23 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:70  I:0    P:1501 SKIP:6652 size=1478 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  37 QP=35.34 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:80  I:70   P:3719 SKIP:4371 size=17736 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  38 QP=38.27 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:76  I:0    P:2010 SKIP:6139 size=2335 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  39 QP=38.31 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:74  I:0    P:1687 SKIP:6470 size=1568 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  40 QP=39.64 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:78  I:0    P:1602 SKIP:6555 size=1412 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  41 QP=35.42 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:88  I:55   P:3556 SKIP:4549 size=15512 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  42 QP=38.49 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:84  I:0    P:1937 SKIP:6212 size=2553 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  43 QP=38.91 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:82  I:1    P:1692 SKIP:6466 size=1594 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  44 QP=38.97 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:86  I:0    P:1579 SKIP:6580 size=1410 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  45 QP=35.52 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:96  I:83   P:3326 SKIP:4751 size=14506 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  46 QP=38.21 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:92  I:1    P:1840 SKIP:6309 size=2535 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  47 QP=39.22 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:90  I:0    P:1458 SKIP:6693 size=1469 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  48 QP=39.78 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:94  I:0    P:1475 SKIP:6681 size=1443 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  49 QP=35.80 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:104 I:43   P:3007 SKIP:5110 size=11393 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  50 QP=38.30 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:100 I:5    P:1671 SKIP:6473 size=2302 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  51 QP=39.14 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:98  I:0    P:1247 SKIP:6912 size=1210 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  52 QP=39.21 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:102 I:0    P:1182 SKIP:6976 size=1295 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  53 QP=35.76 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:112 I:61   P:2610 SKIP:5489 size=10014 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  54 QP=37.88 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:108 I:0    P:1530 SKIP:6617 size=2094 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  55 QP=38.04 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:106 I:1    P:1370 SKIP:6789 size=1385 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  56 QP=39.65 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:110 I:0    P:1184 SKIP:6973 size=1273 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  57 QP=36.38 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:120 I:29   P:2435 SKIP:5696 size=7955 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  58 QP=38.09 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:116 I:0    P:1529 SKIP:6622 size=2100 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  59 QP=39.09 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:114 I:0    P:1148 SKIP:7008 size=1266 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  60 QP=38.23 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:118 I:1    P:1154 SKIP:7000 size=1229 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  61 QP=37.30 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:128 I:20   P:1166 SKIP:6974 size=3361 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  62 QP=37.89 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:124 I:4    P:981  SKIP:7174 size=1607 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  63 QP=38.78 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:122 I:0    P:710  SKIP:7448 size=862 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  64 QP=38.59 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:126 I:0    P:718  SKIP:7441 size=832 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  65 QP=38.34 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:134 I:3    P:450  SKIP:7707 size=1115 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  66 QP=38.11 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:130 I:1    P:486  SKIP:7672 size=900 bytes
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame=  67 QP=40.42 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:132 I:0    P:401  SKIP:7758 size=568 bytes
[aac @ 0000023f4e68e1c0] Trying to remove 656 more samples than there are in the queue
frame=   68 fps= 37 q=-1.0 Lsize=     567kB time=00:00:02.28 bitrate=2034.9kbits/s speed=1.24x
video:543kB audio:20kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.755212%
Input file #0 (inputVideo.mov):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 109 packets read (326736 bytes); 109 frames decoded (108912 samples);
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 0 packets read (0 bytes);
  Input stream #0:2 (video): 68 packets read (38419480 bytes); 68 frames decoded;
  Input stream #0:3 (data): 1 packets read (4 bytes);
  Total: 178 packets (38746220 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (outputVideo.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 68 frames encoded; 68 packets muxed (556221 bytes);
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 107 frames encoded (108912 samples); 108 packets muxed (20041 bytes);
  Total: 176 packets (576262 bytes) muxed
177 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0000023f4f770200] Statistics: 2 seeks, 6 writeouts
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame I:1     Avg QP:35.73  size:155655
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame P:17    Avg QP:35.75  size: 17949
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] frame B:50    Avg QP:38.65  size:  1895
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] consecutive B-frames:  1.5%  0.0%  4.4% 94.1%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] mb I  I16..4:  8.1% 74.9% 17.0%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  1.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 30.2%  4.3%  6.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:57.5%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 20.5%  0.2%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:79.1%  L0:36.3% L1:63.3% BI: 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] 8x8 transform intra:78.0% inter:78.6%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 83.2% 59.8% 20.2% inter: 4.3% 4.0% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] i16 v,h,dc,p: 47% 15% 13% 25%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 21% 20%  5%  5%  4%  9%  4% 10%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 24% 12%  6%  6%  6%  8%  5%  9%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] i8c dc,h,v,p: 58% 17% 22%  3%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] ref P L0: 55.7% 26.9% 17.3%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] ref B L0: 70.3% 24.2%  5.6%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] ref B L1: 85.4% 14.6%
[libx264 @ 0000023f4e5f3740] kb/s:1958.74
[aac @ 0000023f4e68e1c0] Qavg: 127.549
[AVIOContext @ 0000023f4e5f4980] Statistics: 39042622 bytes read, 9 seeks
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the post to show debug-level output from FFMpeg.  I can clearly see that it recognizes timecode.  I don't know why Quicktime doesn't see it in the output and Adobe Premier does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some detective work, I've started using a command line that converts the video and keeps the timecode intact:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mov -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v mpeg4 output.mp4
```